# Laravel Unit Testing - Run All Tests

Tags: laravel, phpunit, laravel-4

I'm pretty new to both Laravel and PHPUnit, and I'm using Laravel 4 on Ubuntu 12.04.

When I run `phpunit` from my project's home directory, it runs the ExampleTest.php test that comes with Laravel. I created my own sample test (exactly like their example and in the same directory, only the file and test are renamed and do something different), and ran `phpunit` again like before; but it still only ran ExampleTest.php--not my created test. But if I run `phpunit path/to/myTest`, it runs my test just fine. So I feel like this is a dumb question, but how do I run all of the tests with one command (I thought `phpunit` should've done that)?

Thanks for the help!

Comment: what is the actual 'path/to/myTest' and the test filename?

Comment: `app/tests/TestCreateEvent.php`

Answer (score 37, accepted):

Your tests need to finish with ...Test.php to run automatically. So change

```
app/tests/TestCreateEvent.php
```

to

```
app/tests/CreateEventTest.php
```

and it should work.

Also make sure you rename the model inside the test to `"class CreateEventTest extends TestCase"`

Comment: I figured it was something simple. Thanks!

Comment: One question, why does TestCase work? Its not ended with Test.php

Comment: TestCase has no tests. each test method must be prefixed with "test". testSomething() {}